# Is there a way to have 8 audio inputs on the raspberry PI4?

Tags: gpio, audio, hifiberry

Maybe it's kind of a weird question, but I have a small project for which I need 8 audio inputs (not outputs) on the Raspberry Pi 4, without using USB.

Are there any ways to achieve this on the Raspberry Pi and if yes how?